# Troubles with listview in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to make a list view with both images and text inside a fragment but i just cant get it to work.I get some kind of an error that tells me that i attempted to invoke the set Adapter method on a null object.What am i doing wrong

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
String[] listviewTitle = new String[]{"Drew Parker","Maggie Smith","Michael John","Luisa Miller","Loredana Marie","Cristopher Smidth","Michelle Acapella","John Fitzgerald"

};
int[] listviewImage = new int[]{
        R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.profile,

};
String[] listviewShortDescription = new String[]{
        "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description",
        "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description",
};

public SecondFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
        hm.put("listview_discription", listviewShortDescription[i]);
        hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[i]));
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_discription"};
    int[] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description};

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.tab2fragment, from, to);
    ListView listView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_withimages_andnames,container,false);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the widgets initialization from onCreate and place it inside the onCreateView as below.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_withimages_andnames,container,false);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.tab2fragment, from, to);

    ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


return view;   }
```

and also replace

`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_view)`

by

`view.findViewById(R.id.list_view)`

Because you should get your recycler view from the fragment's layout which is being initialized in the onCreateView, not from the activity

Comment: An explanation of why, would greatly improve the quality of your answer and thus increase the chance of it being up-voted.

Comment: I says i cannot resolve symbol aList, from, to at the SimpleAdapter

Comment: Nvm got it.Thanks